# Notification Window is not attached to page in Vaadin

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin, vaadin7

**Issue:**
Step 1: Restore down the browser window.
Step 2: Click on Notification Icon.
Step 3: Now maximize the browser window.

Issue Observed: The notification window stays at the same place. Doesn't move to the new position.
The same is working fine here : https://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/#!dashboard

**Code:**

```
        //Window Content
        setWidth(340.0f,Unit.PIXELS);
        setClosable(false);
        setResizable(false);
        setDraggable(false);
        addCloseShortcut(KeyCode.ESCAPE,null);
        //Setting mainLayout which is a vertical layout
        setContent(mainLayout);
        setPositionY(event.getClientY() - event.getRelativeY() + 35);
        setPositionX(event.getClientX() - event.getRelativeX() - 265);
```

**Screen:**

Restored the browser window and clicked on notification button.
[image: Restored the window and clicked on notification button]
Now maximizing the window.
 **observed:** It doesn't move to the new position which should be next to notification button. Instead stays at same place.

[image: Now maximizing the window]

Any support regarding the same will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You calculate the postion once on server side.  The client does not get a "formula" to recalculate that again.  You might be better off solving this via CSS or maybe some addon can help here.